# Variable seems to be not defined

Tags: python

I am working on a project to draw a graph with the help of turtle and I want to read and write the price to a text file, but I keep failing. Now, the program doesn't read the price from the file, and I get the error that my price isn't defined. I have also tried to define it as global but that doesn't help. Please help me, I am in serious trouble.

```
from random import randint
import turtle
import time
global price
def getprice():
    getprice = open("price.txt", 'r')
    price = int(getprice.readlines())
    getprice.close()


turtle.up()
turtle.setup(width=1000, height=563)
turtle.goto(-495,0)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.pensize(5)
turtle.shape("circle")
turtle.down()
print(price)
```

Comment: `global price` in the global scope does absolutely nothing. You would need to use `global price` inside your function. But that isn't the right way ot do this. Rather, you should *return* price from your function

Comment: from random import randint
import turtle
import time
price = 0
def getprice():
    getprice = open("price.txt", 'r')
    for line in getprice:
        price = getprice.readlines()
    getprice.close()
    return price
    

turtle.up()
turtle.setup(width=1000, height=563)
turtle.goto(-495,0)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.pensize(5)
turtle.shape("circle")
turtle.down()
getprice()
print(price)

Comment: im keep getting as a result 0

Comment: Your code in the function `getprice()` throws a TypeError because you are attempting to call `int()` on the list returned by `readlines()`.  It should be `readline()`, but if you are not getting that error then maybe the function is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the return value to a variable:

```
def getprice():
    with open("price.txt", 'r') as lines:
        return int(lines.readlines()[-1])

price = getprice()
print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each price is a line in price.txt,

```
def getprice():
    pricefile = open("price.txt", 'r')
    price = []
    for line in pricefile:
        price.append(line)
    return price

the_price = getprice()
```

`the_price` will contain each line in price.txt